# C# Window_KeyUp() not working

Tags: c#, keyup

Hey I have this piece of code:

```
private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (playing == false)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
    {
        pictureBox6.Image = Form.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
        player.Stop();
        player.Close();
        playing = false;
    }
}
```

I'ts not working but the Window_KeyDown() works.

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: What part of it is not working? Is the event being fired? Are you sure the handler is wired up correctly to the form and/or the controller?

Comment: The events are not fired after you release the key.

Comment: Do you have the event setup for a specific controller or the form? I believe the keyUp method gets called if the target controller is in focus.

Comment: Do you have this for a Form KeyUp event handler?

Comment: @Steve Iam afraid i don't.

Comment: @RezaShirazian yes, the event is setup specificly for the key D.1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The KeyUp event (also KeyDown and KeyPress) are triggered at the form level only if the form has

```
KeyPreview = true;
```

[MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)

> true if the form will receive all key events; false if the currently
>   selected control on the form receives key events. The default is
>   false.

Comment: Well i already defined KeyPreview = true; as KeyDown works fine.

Comment: Well that's interesting, what do you do in the KeyDown event? `e.Handled=true;`

Comment: stop the sound triggered by KeyDown event and also change the image of  a button, pretty simple but won't work.

Comment: Whats with the "e.Handled=true;"?

Comment: If you don't want a key to be further processed you could change the `KeyEventArgs` argument e passed to the event handler and set e.Handled = true;

Comment: Could you confirm me that you have hooked the KeyUp event in the designer of your form?

Comment: Oh, how careless I was, that was the problem, now it works. Thanks